# Copy files from within a docker container to local machine

Tags: docker

Is it possible to copy files to a local machine by running a command inside of a docker container.  I am aware of `docker cp <containerId>:container/file/path /host/file/path`  However, my understanding is that this has to be run from outside of the docker container. Is there a way to do it or something similar from within?

For some context I have a python script that is run inside of a docker container with something like the following command `docker run -ti -rm --net=host buildServer:5000/myProgram /myProgram.py -h`.  I would like to retrieve the files that are generated from this program so they can be edited.  I could run the docker container in detached mode, `docker cp` the desired file and the shutdown the container.  However, I would like to be able to abstract this away from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers *by design* don't have any access to the host filesystem unless you provide it explicitly via volume mounts.  So, in your example, you could do something like:

```
docker run -ti -v /tmp/data:/data -rm --net=host buildServer:5000/myProgram /myProgram.py -h
```

And within the container, the `/data` directory would be mapped to `/tmp/data` on your host.  You could then copy files into `/data` to get at them on your host.

This assumes that you're running Docker on Linux.  If you are using Windows or OS X there may be additional steps, since in those environments Docker is actually running on a Linux virtual machine and volume access may or may not behave as expected (I don't use those platforms so I can't comment authoritatively).

For more information:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume